# Inserting large datasets into SQLite db becomes very slow over time

Tags: java, performance, database, sqlite

I'm using the program below to insert values from very large .csv files (~2.5 million lines) into an SQLite DB. It starts very fast, but begins to slow over time, before eventually hanging indefinitely at around 900,000 lines. My hunch says that it's eating up memory somehow, but not quite a memory leak, since it never throws an `OutOfMemoryException` or similar. To be clear, the program never fails, or crashes. It just gets slower until it stops progressing. All other processes on my laptop are also affected, and eventually it takes ~10 seconds to even register mouse movements.

I'm not very experienced with databases, so it could easily be something stupid I'm doing with how I execute the `INSERT` statement. The most recent modification I made was to use `PreparedStatement.addBatch()` and `PreparedStatement.executeBatch()` and despite reading the documentation, I'm still not very clear on whether I'm using them correctly.

```
public class Database{

        public static void main(String[] args){
            Connection c = connect("db.db");
//            createTable(c);
            addCSVToDatabase(c, "test-10000.csv");
//            print(c);
            disconnect(c);
        }

        public static void createTable(Connection c) {
            Statement stmt;
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE results("
                    + "ID            INTEGER    NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + "TITLE         TEXT       NOT NULL, "
                    + "URL           TEXT       NOT NULL    UNIQUE, "
                    + "BEAN  BLOB"
                    + ");"; 
            System.out.println("QUERY: " + sql);
            try {
                stmt = c.createStatement();
                stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
        }

        public static void addCSVToDatabase(Connection c, String csvFile){

            BufferedReader reader = null;
            int x = 0;
            DBEntryBean b;
            String[] vals;
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
            ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
            PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
            String sql = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO results("
                    + "TITLE, "
                    + "URL, "
                    + "BEAN"
                    + ") VALUES(?, ?, ?);";
            try{
                pstmt = c.prepareStatement(sql);
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(csvFile), "UTF-8"));
                c.setAutoCommit(false);

                for(String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;){

                    vals = line.split("\\|"); // Each line is of the form: "title|URL|...|...|..."
                    b = new DBEntryBean();
                    b.setTitle(vals[0]);
                    b.setURL(vals[1]);

                    pstmt.setString(Constants.DB_COL_TITLE, b.getTitle());      
                    pstmt.setString(Constants.DB_COL_URL, b.getURL());  

                    // Store the DBEntryBean in the table so I can retrieve it, rather than construct a new one every time I need it.
                    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
                    oos.writeObject(b);
                    pstmt.setBytes(Constants.DB_COL_BEAN, baos.toByteArray());
                    pstmt.addBatch();
                    pstmt.executeBatch(); 
                    System.out.println("Line: " + x++);
                }
            } catch (Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); 
            } finally{
                try{ 
                    if(pstmt != null){ pstmt.close(); }
                    c.setAutoCommit(true);
                } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
        }

        private static Connection connect(String path) {

            String url = "jdbc:sqlite:" + path;
            Connection conn = null;
            try {
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            return conn;
        }

        private static void disconnect(Connection c) {
            try{ if(c != null){ c.close(); }
            } catch(SQLException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
        }

        private static void print(Connection c){
            Statement stmt = null;
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM results;";
            ResultSet rs = null;
            try {
                stmt = c.createStatement();
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                while(rs.next()){
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("TITLE"));
                }
            } catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
        }


    }
```

Comment: It seems you posted a similar question earlier http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151947/efficiently-adding-huge-amounts-of-data-from-csv-files-into-an-sqlite-db-in-java. Did you intend to edit that one? Or can you explain the difference between the two?

Comment: @Tunaki As I explained in the comments of that previous post, the nature of the question has changed. That question was to do with efficiently inserting large amounts of data, whereas this question is asking for help solving possible memory management problems.